# How can I Union two DB2 tables with the same structure except four additional columns in one of the tables?

Tags: db2, union

How can I Union two DB2 tables with the same structure except four additional columns in one of the tables?
I have gone through other similar questions and tried the following options. None of them worked. I am working on DB2.

1)

```
Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 from Table1
Union
Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Null as Col4, Null as Col5 from Table2
```

SQL Error [42703]: NULL IS NOT VALID IN THE CONTEXT WHERE IT IS USED. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=3.62.56

2)

```
Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 from Table1
Union
Select Col1, Col2, Col3, '' as Col4, '' as Col5 from Table2
```

SQL Error [42825]: THE CORRESPONDING COLUMNS, 17, OF THE OPERANDS OF A SET OPERATOR ARE NOT COMPATIBLE. SQLCODE=-415, SQLSTATE=42825, DRIVER=3.62.56

Please advice.

Comment: The data types of the corresponding columns must be compatible. Please, provide the `CREATE TABLE` statement text for both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
cast(NULL as varchar(20)) as Col4
```

Instead of varchar(20) use whatever type the column has in the other table